# Debug Vert.x app using Gradle and VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vert.x, vscode-debugger

I'm working with a *Vert.x* app with verticles written in *Java*. The app uses a MainVerticle to start and uses *Gradle* for its construction. I'm using *VS Code* as IDE/Code Editor since it is really simple and lightweight. However it has been really difficult to find a way to debug my code. How do I configure **build.gradle** and **.vscode/launch.json** to enable debug options?

So far this is my command to start in build.gradle file:

```
run {
  args = [ 'run', mainVerticleName, "--redeploy=$watchForChange", "--launcher-class=$mainClassName", "--on-redeploy=$doOnChange" ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm woking on VS Code for Java devs and my microservices uses Eclipse Vertx.io. It's is easy to configure for maven. Use maven create vertx project and modify it own usage.

I have modified it and got similar project (not eaxact cannot show full code)

package com.test.service;

```
import io.vertx.config.ConfigRetriever;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions;
import io.vertx.core.Promise;

public class Application extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {
    ConfigRetriever retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx);
    retriever.getConfig(
        res -> {
          try {
            if (res.failed()) {
              .....
            } else {
              startPromise.complete();
              vertx.deployVerticle(
                  new TestServiceVerticle(),
                  new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(res.result()));              
            }
          } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            ...
            startPromise.fail(e.getMessage());
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.5.0</exec-maven-plugin.version>

    <vertx.version>3.8.5</vertx.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit-jupiter.version>

    <main.verticle>test.test.service.Application</main.verticle>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-stack-depchain</artifactId>
        <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-web-api-contract</artifactId>
      <version>${vertx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-config</artifactId>
      <version>${vertx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
                    <Main-Verticle>${main.verticle}</Main-Verticle>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <artifactSet></artifactSet>
              <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.jar
              </outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>io.vertx.core.Launcher</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>run</argument>
            <argument>${main.verticle}</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

hope it will help.

debugging settings

```
     {
                "type": "java",
                "name": "Run service",
                "request": "launch",
                "mainClass": "io.vertx.core.Launcher",
                "args": "run test.test.service.Application"
      }
```

Comment: I used only the last configuration you sent for launch.json and te vscode version 1.45 now works normally.